# Dynamically allocating an array of integers,storing them in a file and finding the average of them in c

Tags: c, file, dynamic, malloc

I am currently solving an assignment about dynamic memory allocation and it says that i should dynamically allocate an array of integers ,store them in the form of table in a file,later find and print average of those numbers.But when it comes to printing the average,i get wrong results.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
  FILE *fp=fopen("some.txt","w+");
  printf("How many numbers are you going to input?\n");
  int n,i;
  scanf("%d",&n);

  int *tab;
  int sum=0;
  tab=(int*)malloc(n*sizeof(int));
  for(i=0;i<n && !(feof(fp));i++){
    printf("Enter a number:\n");
    scanf("%d",tab+i);
    fprintf(fp,"%d",*(tab+i));
  }
  for(i=0;i<n && !(feof(fp));i++){
    fscanf(fp,"%d",tab+i);
    printf("%d\t",*(tab+i));
    sum+=*(tab+i);
  }
  float mean=sum/(float)n;
  printf("%f\n",mean);
  free(tab);
}
```

This is an example input and it is supposed to print all the numbers i had written into the file and as the value of the average at the end it should have printed 4.6666(something like this for these specific three inputs)

```
    How many numbers are you going to input?
    3

    Enter a number:
    4

    Enter a number:
    5

    Enter a number:
    5

    4   1.333333
```

Comment: OT: For ease of readability and understanding: 1) please consistently indent the code.  Indent after every opening brace '{'.  Unindent before every closing brace '}'.  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces.  2) separate code blocks: `for` `if` `else` `while` `do...while` `switch` `case` `default` via a single blank line.  3) follow the axiom:  *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*

Comment: OT: when calling `fopen()`, always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  If not successful call: `perror()` to output both your error message and the text reason the system thinks the error occurred to `stderr`

Comment: do not use _feof_ but check _scanf_ and  _fscanf_ return 1 (in your cases)

Comment: OT: regarding: `tab=(int*)malloc(n*sizeof(int));`  1) the returned type is `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug, etc.  2) always check (!-NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  If not successful, call `perror()` to output both your error message and the text reason the system thinks the error occurred to `stderr`

Comment: regarding: `for(i=0;i<n && !(feof(fp));i++){`  the expression: `!(foef(fp))`  does not do what you are expecting it to do.  Similar considerations exist for: `for(i=0;i<n && !(feof(fp));i++){`

Comment: OT: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, including `fscanf()`, always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.  (They return the number of successful input conversion specifications)

Comment: OT:  for ease of readability and understanding;  1) insert an appropriate space: after commas, after semicolons, inside parens, inside braces, inside brackets, around C operators

Comment: after writing all the integers to the file, the code needs to move the file position pointer back to the start of the file.  One way to do this is: `rewind( fp );`

Comment: OT: the posted code makes no real use of the 'tab[]`  as there is no need to keep all the numbers input.  Suggest a simple `int temp;` and using temp' everywhere there is currently a reference to `tab[]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two main problems in your code.

1. When writing the data to the file in the first loop you should separate the numbers by a space or newline, e.g.

   ```
   fprintf(fp,"%d\n",*(tab+i));
   ```
2. Between writing and reading the file you should go back to the beginning. Between the two loops insert

   ```
   fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);
   ```

There are a few more errors in the code that may lead to problems in some cases:

Function `feof()` can be used only **after** a read operation, e.g. after `fscanf` to distinguish between EOF or errors.

You should `fclose` the file when you are done.

You should check the result of all functions, e.g. that `fopen` did not return a `NULL` pointer, that `scanf` or `fscanf` successfully converted the expected number of items, ...

Comment: add _feof_ must not be used but OP have to check scanf and fscanf return 1 (in is cases). May be explain more saying without separator between integer prints the result is one integer

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a '\n' after each entered number and set the file position to the beginning of the file, before trying to read the content of the file.. Look:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
FILE *fp=fopen("some.txt","w+");
printf("How many numbers are you going to input?\n");
int n,i;
scanf("%d",&n);

int *tab;
int sum=0;
tab=(int*)malloc(n*sizeof(int));
for(i=0;i<n && !(feof(fp));i++){
    printf("Enter a number:\n");
    scanf("%d",tab+i);
    fprintf(fp,"%d\n",*(tab+i));
}
rewind(fp);
for(i=0;i<n && !(feof(fp));i++){
    fscanf(fp,"%d",tab+i);
    printf("%d\t",*(tab+i));
    sum+=*(tab+i);
}
float mean=sum/(float)n;
printf("%f\n",mean);
free(tab);
}
```